# Default publishing rules for pages with embedded dynamic component presentations

Tags: publishing, 2013

I'm trying to confirm a page publishing scenario.

Setup:

- *Article* schema
- *Article Full* component template (CT) with both set:

  - `Published as a Dynamic Component`
  - `Allow on Page Using Dynamic Assembly`
- *Article Summary* CT with just:

  - `Published as a Dynamic Component` set

If I publish an *Article* component, both dynamic component presentation (DCP) variations publish:

- Article Full
- Article Summary

If I publish a page that has an Article component with one template (e.g. *Article Full*), the corresponding DCP (Article + Article Full) will also be published.

**Question: should the Article Summary DCP also publish?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. When publishing a page, no other items are are resolved. Component Presentations on the page are rendered, but only if the Page Template explicitly does this (so if your page contains DCPs, but your PT does not call RenderComponentPresentation or an equivalent function, the DCP will not be published).

It is only when publishing components that resolving gets interesting:

1. A DCP is published for every CT which is linked to the component's schema
2. All pages containing the component with a static CT, which have already been published are republished
3. All components which link to the component you are publishing are published (and components that link to those, etc. etc.)

If you want to have the Article Summary published also, you could call `RenderComponentPresentation(article,summaryCT)` from within a TBB in the Article Full CT (or your PT). Be careful of unpublishing though - Editors might have the expectation that unpublishing the page would also unpublish the Article Full and/or Summary DCP - neither will be. This is why it is sometimes wise to stick to static CTs unless strictly necessary.

Comment: I vividly remember internalizing those three points the hard way: (1. seeing *all* DCP variations in the broker, 2. wondering why a non-published page wouldn't publish, and 3. link propogation fun). But interestingly I've missed the distinction for *publishing pages* (publishes the page and just the CPs on them).

Comment: I remember getting a nasty surprise from this. My page needed several different dynamic renderings of the same component. (The page rendered different views of itself depending on parameters). I only wanted the content managers to have to put the component on the page once. Ended up with an events system to fill the gap.

Comment: @DominicCronin, well now you know all you needed was a `RenderComponentPresentation()`! ;-) Or was that for a 5.2 customer?

Comment: I just realized my initial statement about Component Presentations on a page being resolved was a bit misleading - actually there is no resolving going on here, the PT is responsible for explicitly rendering the CPS - have updated the answer.

Comment: I think I'd made the same error with my answer below.  I too have updated mine.

Comment: I removed references to "resolving" to keep it clear. Thanks all.

Comment: @AlvinReyes - the use case was several *dynamic* renderings on the same page.

Comment: Following up on this, I see how to use `RendercomponentPresentation()` to *publish* items that aren't even on the page. I ask if this [is like `AddBinary()` in this question](http://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/2778/46). However, even with a (checked-in) page that has a Page Template with no TBBs, its DCPs show in `Items to Publish`.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered in the [Publishing items](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL_Tridion_2013/concept_56BCD7B2A1994C76B940751B2458D8E0) section of the online documentation (login required).

Rather interesting is that the online documentation says the following of publishing Components:

> If a Component is based on an allowed Schema that is used in a dynamic
>   Component Template, **only** the dynamic Component Presentation is
>   published.

From memory, and inline with what Will says above, I do not think that this is correct.  It is not **only** the DCP(s) that will be published, but also published Components that link to it too.

Comment: That's definitely my favorite reference on what gets (re)published. I understand pages that have the component embedded (statically) are also (re)published. But I don't think pages that have the component embedded dynamically are published. [Shameless plug][We have three scenarios for CPs on pages](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/03/dynamic-vs-static-component.html)[/shameless plug].

Comment: Thanks Alvin.  I have updated my answer slightly to clarify.