# What is difference in Static CP and DCP

Tags: componentpresentation

I have read some article and detail regarding Static CP and DCP but want difference in points.
like.
1. if i have read that if you create static CP then any changes in CP you need to publish all pages but in DCP it's not required . I want to know how , In DCP what should i need to publish.

Thanks
Bhagat

Answer (score 3):

With a DCP you publish the component instead of the page.

A very common use case is headers and footers (perhaps including navigation). Since these components are used by (almost) all pages you want to be able to update them on the full site in one go.

When you put a component presentation on a page with a Dynamic Component Template Tridion will generate server-side code to include that CP when rendering the page instead of rendering the content "inline" and this allows you to manage the publishing of that content without having to (re)publish the page itself.

Comment: so as you say in DCP you have to publish component. Is it true if when we publish a component then all CT which are associate with that schema , will get publish ?

Comment: Yes, but not quite in the way you phrased it (though worth its own question). When you publish a component directly, it will publish all possible DCPs, one for each "dynamic" template associated with its schema. I'm making a distinction between publishing a DCP (rendered content) and a Component Template (just the part that renders the CP).

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you're referencing Will Price's post "[DCP Etiquette – Why would you make a Component Template ‘Dynamic’?](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/dcp-etiquette-why-would-you-make-a-component-template-dynamic)"

To be clear from an *authoring* perspective, in either a static *or* dynamic case you can publish either the content or the pages. I have a follow-up to Will's post, [describing what publishes what](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/10/lets-play-what-published-that-aka-sdl.html); here are the relevant parts:

- **Publish a page and all of its CPs get updated** (rendered into the page or referenced as Nuno describes), ***including DCPs added to it***--no need to publish these DCPs separately
- **Publish a component and it will queue all (already published) pages** that use it statically *and* (all variations of) its DCPs will get published

Subtle points worth mentioning:

- Referencing a DCP in a template will "publish" it (but not resolve it when queued) at least with `RenderComponentPresentation()`
- When a Page publishes its embedded DCPs, it only publishes the specific Component Presentations included on it
- This differs from publishing a Component directly which will publish *all* of its DCP variations

For a more tangible example see the answers my question:
[Default publishing rules for pages with embedded dynamic component presentations](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/q/1992/46)